# How can i generate a unique key for my key prop inside a map? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
class Board extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    nrows: 5,
    ncols: 5,
    chanceLightStartsOn: 0.25
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasWon: false,
      board: this.createBoard(),
      counter: 0,

    };

      this.createBoard = this.createBoard.bind(this);
      this.keyCount = this.keyCount.bind(this);
  }
[...]
   render() {

    const mainBoard = Array.from({length: this.props.nrows}).map(() => (
        <tr>
          {Array.from({length: this.props.ncols}).map((x, index) => (
            <Cell key={this.state.counter + 1} onClick={() => this.flipCellsAround()} isLit={this.props.chanceLightStartsOn > Math.random()} />
            ))}
        </tr>
      ));

    return (
      <table className="Board">
        <tbody>
          <h1>BOARD</h1>
          {mainBoard}
        </tbody>
      </table>

    );
```

I would like that on every iteration my `key` increments by one so it is unique. I have tried so many things but haven't succeeded. Is it possible to pass a function to the `key`  which then increments it by 1 on each iteration?

Comment: there is a npm module called `uuid` check it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Doesn't this work? key={index}

Comment: @JonWilson no i tried that it just gives this: `0,1,2,3,4`  `0,1,2,3,4`, `0,1,2,3,4`  `0,1,2,3,4` for each cell in each row of my table if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the `index` variable to the key prop **and combine it with the index from the outer `map()`**, if you are not resizing your table. ideally it would be a number that has some logical connection to the contents of the column so react would know to re-render your column if the `Cell` component has changed.

```
const mainBoard = Array.from({length: this.props.nrows}).map((ignored, rowIndex) => (
    <tr>
      {Array.from({length: this.props.ncols}).map((x, idx) => (
        <Cell key={rowIndex * this.props.nrows + idx} onClick={() => this.flipCellsAround()} isLit={this.props.chanceLightStartsOn > Math.random()} />
        ))}
    </tr>
  ));
```

heres a snippet to illustrate the point:

```js
var rows = Array.from({ length: 10 });
var cols = Array.from({ length: 5 });
var mainBoard = rows.map((ignored, rowIndex, rows) => {
  return cols.map((ignoredCol, colIndex, col) => {
    return rows.length * rowIndex + colIndex;
  })
});

console.log(mainBoard)
```

Comment: or it can be purely random as suggested by @blacksheep on the question itself

Comment: I need all my keys to be unique though. If I use the `index` when I inspect my table I see the keys are: `0,1,2,3,4` `0,1,2,3,4`,  `0,1,2,3,4` `0,1,2,3,4`  for each cell in each row of my table  if that makes sense?

Comment: @AngelaInniss try this version

Comment: -This actually works perfectly and is what i wanted - Thank you and for the ilustration.